# Exporting output of a command to a variable only if succesful (Bash set -e)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, error-handling, command

I would like the following script to fail. (and still print err to stderr)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
export X=$(echo a)
export Y=$(ekko b)
echo ok
```

Edit: Question revised based on @ray comment

Comment: the script will fail at `Y=$(ekko b)` and print to stderr `line 4: ekko: command not found`, isn't that what you want?

Comment: You're right. I'll correct the question and now I got the answer too:) thanks

Comment: Don't forget [to accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the export command. The solution is to separate the assignment with the export:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
X=$(echo a)
Y=$(ekko b)
export X
export Y
echo ok
```